# Go to another intent when login to facebook was succesfull

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-intent

I've created an app with a facebook login button. I want that, when I successfully login to facebook to go to another intent... I've written some code, but I've got some 'weird' errors (my opinion)

Here is my code so far:

```
public class LogIn extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false); 

        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackmanager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Intent i = new Intent(this, MainPannel.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }

            public void onCancel() {
            }

            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
               }
        });
    }

    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("LogIn Page")
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }
}
```

These are the errors:

```
Error:(33, 9) error: cannot find symbol variable loginButton
Error:(33, 37) error: cannot find symbol variable view
Error:(37, 38) error: cannot find symbol variable callbackmanager
Error:(41, 28) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent
```

Please help :(

Comment: What have you tried so far? That is a very broad question and it's answer is available in the getting started page of the  library.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

First implement facebook with application.

```
    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
        // If using in a fragment
        loginButton.setFragment(this);    
        // Other app specific specialization

        // Callback registration
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
        Intent i = new Intent(this,Another.class);
        startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android

Comment: it gives me the error "cannot resolve symbol 'view'"

Comment: loginButton  is Facebook login button not android.widget.Button

Comment: yes, i know... it just doesn't see it...  neither "loginButton" and "callbackmanager"

Answer (score 0):

Use com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton for facebook login button widget.

And import these in java file.

```
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
```

Comment: I've tried to clean the project and re-run it, but it was unsuccessfully